# How to display rtf in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, xaml, azure, windows-phone-8

I am working on a News Application on WP8.1 and news body text is formatted as rtf. And below is a sample body text of a news item. But I cannot display body text as formatted before in Windows Phone.

> {\rtf1\fbidis\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fswiss\fprq2\fcharset0 Arial;}{\f1\fnil\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}} {\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue0;\red255\green0\blue0;\red255\green255\blue0;} \viewkind4\uc1\pard\ltrpar\sl276\slmult1\cf1\highlight2\lang2055\ul\b\f0\fs20 Test for \highlight3 RTF\highlight0 RTF TEST TETST \par \highlight3 www.google.com\highlight0\par \pard\ltrpar\cf0\lang1033\ulnone\b0\f1\fs17\par }

How can I display rtf above in WP ?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A Windows Phone Runtime app can display RTF in a [RichEditBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.richeditbox.aspx):

RichEditBox1.[Document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.richeditbox.document.aspx).[SetText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.text.itextdocument.settext.aspx)([TextSetOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.text.textsetoptions.aspx).FormatRTF,rtfString);

See [Quickstart: Adding text input and editing controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh700391.aspx#richeditbox) and the [XAML text editing sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-text-editing-sample-fb0493ad) for more info.

There isn't an in-box RTF control for Silverlight apps, but for simple RTF you can parse it yourself and then load the blocks into a [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/apps/system.windows.controls.richtextbox(v=vs.105).aspx).